# Objective-C: downloading

Tags: ios, objective-c, download

I use this code for download file.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.mp3"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:false];

NSString *stringURL = @"link";
NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

and to know if file exists

```
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:false];
```

I want to know when downloading was finished(not file exists) and create check:

```
if (downloading was finished) {
//action
}
```

How to do it?

**UPD**

```
if (indexPath.row == 1) {

                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.mp3"];
                BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:false];
                if (!fileExists) {

                         UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                                       alertControllerWithTitle:@"1"
                                                       message:@"1"
                                                       preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
                         UIAlertAction* actionAdd = [UIAlertAction
                                                     actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                                     {
                        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


                        _spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
                        _spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
                        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                        cell.accessoryView = _spinner;
                        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = _spinner;
                        [_spinner startAnimating];

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{     
                        NSString *dataUrl = @"link";
                        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:dataUrl];


                        NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
                        dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                        if (((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).statusCode == 200) {
                        [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
                        }
                        }];

                        [downloadTask resume];
                         });
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                        cell.accessoryView = nil;

                        if (fileExists) {
                        [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
                        [cell setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
                        }
                        });
                        });
                        }];

                         UIAlertAction* actionCancel = [UIAlertAction
                                                        actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                        style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                        handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                                        {
                                                            [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                        }];
                         [alert addAction:actionAdd];
                         [alert addAction :actionCancel];
                         alert.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
                         alert.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 3.4, self.view.bounds.size.height / 4.0, 1.0, 1.0);
                         [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
                     }
                     if (fileExists) {
                         [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"Segue" sender: self];
                     }
                 }
```

Comment: Don't use `dataWithContentsOfURL` to download network-based URLs. See the warning in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1547245-datawithcontentsofurl).

Comment: While I fully agree that you should not use `dataWithContentsOfURL` (at least on the main queue), the simple answer to your original question is that you know the download is complete when the `dataWithContentsOfURL` method finishes. When the next line of code is reached, the download is finished.

Comment: @rmaddy If you click on a cell, the download starts. In my application 40 cells and the user can click on all cells. If I use `dataWithContentsOfURL` my application will lag?

Comment: Your app will freeze until every call to `dataWithContentsOfURL` finishes (assuming you are calling it on the main queue).

Comment: @rmaddy If I wrap hiding my code in question in this code:  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
}); my app not freeze?

Comment: Oh yes, it will freeze for sure since you are specifically stating that you want the long download process to happen on the main queue. **Never** do that. Use `NSURLSession` as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you should use an NSURLSession data task:

```
NSString *dataUrl = stringURL;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:dataUrl];


NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
  dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
  if (((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).statuscode == 200) {
       [data writeToFile:<filePathHere> atomically:YES];
    }
}];

[downloadTask resume];
```

Comment: If I use this code my activity indicator not work. Why?

Comment: By not working, do you mean you can't dismiss it from inside the block? If so, wrap hiding the spinner in this code: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        
    });`

Comment: I add my code in question in **UPD** I add `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ }); ` but my activity indicator not work. Please check

Comment: I add code from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in question(UPD). If I use `NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];` my indicator work fine during file downloading. But I use your code my indicator doesn’t work but file downloading.

Answer (score 0):

`NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];` performs synchronously. That means, that your code after this line is not executing, until `dataWithContentsOfURL` is completed downloading of the file. So you can simply do in following way:

```
NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if ( urlData != nil ) { //data downloaded
//action
}
```